# Find vowels in each word from a sentence entered by the user (java)

Tags: java, split, sentence, text-segmentation

I have a program that gives the following output:

> Enter a Sentence: I am new to java
>
> I
>
> am
>
> new
>
> to
>
> java
>
> Number of vowels in: I am new to java = 6

My problem is that i need to get the vowels in each word of the sentence entered by the user.

For e.g. the output should be something like:

> Enter a Sentence: I am new to java
>
> I (1)
>
> am        (1)
>
> new       (1)
>
> to        (1)
>
> java      (2)
>
> Number of vowels in: I am new to java = 6

I am using .split() to separate sentence entered and switch /.charAT statements for vowel checking.

Can someone please help me achieve this outcome?

Comment: You gave what the final output should look like, but you also need to detail what you are getting and how you are getting it.

Comment: I am getting user input using:                                              Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String sentence;
System.out.print("Enter a Sentence: ");
sentence = input.nextLine();
SentenceSplit(sentence); //method made to split user input

Comment: Don't forget *Y* for example "the sky is beautiful today."  The standard vowels are A E I O U and *Sometimes* Y.

Comment: take a look at here String based algorithm questions will help you much http://bekoc.blogspot.com/2012/07/in-this-post-i-try-to-implement.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole solution only needs a couple of lines of code:

```
for (String word : sentence.split(" +"))
    System.out.println(word + " (" + 
      word.replaceAll("[^aeiouAEIOU]", "")
      .length() + ")");
```

The way it works is the call to `replaceAll()` removes all non-vowels, so what remains is only vowels, then you simply take the length of that vowel-only String.

Comment: I've changed it to use the same technique, but display what you asked. Try it now.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to build one String and loop through every char and check for a vowel.

```
String test = "I am new to Java";
int vowels = 0;

for (char c: test.toLowerCase().toCharArray()){
    if(c == 'a' || c =='e' || c=='i' || c=='o' || c=='u' ){
        vowels++;
    }
}
System.out.println(test + " Contains: " +vowels +" Vowels");
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
String n = "I am in Madurai";
int count = 0;
char c[] = new char[n.length()];
n.getChars(0, n.length, c, 0);

for(int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    if (c[i] == 'a' || c[i] == 'e' || c[i] == 'i' || c[i] == 'o' || c[i] == 'u')
        count++;
}
System.out.println("Number of vowels in a given sentence: " + count);
```

**Output:**

```
Number of vowels in a given sentence: 7
```